# Return Title Case respecting capital letters in middle of word?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is a duplicate (not sure how I'd word a search to find it for sure because my google-fu is weak today)

I have some javascript code to convert the first letter of every word to uppercase. I need to alter it so that it respects oddball capitalization that you might see in last names (e.g.: McGuire, MacGonnacle, O'Brien).
Essentially, the idea is to **force the first letter of each word to be capitalized but not convert all the other letters to lowercase if entered in uppercase**.

Here's the code snippet :

```
function properCase(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    return str.replace(/(\b)([a-z\WA-Z\W])/g,
             function (firstLetter) {
                 return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
             });
}
```

It's probably because it's the end of the day on a weekend but what modifications do I need to make?

Comment: Just *dont* call `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: What about iPod, iOS, jQuery..?

Comment: It's for a user's last name so I doubt that anyone is running around with the last name of jQuery :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of it, just drop the str.toLowerCase();

```
function properCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\b)([a-z\WA-Z\W])/g,function (firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

running `properCase('mcCormick')` returns `McCormick`

Edit:

Taking a look at the regex, I think you probably don't need that whole expression (though it depends on your use case, as all things do)

```
function properCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)([a-z])/,function (firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

This will uppercase the beginning of any word that starts with a letter.  Ex `properCase('mcCormick is *an excellent duelist')` returns `"McCormick Is *an Excellent Duelist"`

Comment: That was it. Wow... end of day brain fry. Thanks man. The amusing bit is that I got the regex but missed the toLowerCase.

Comment: Why did you include `\W`?

Comment: hmm, I didnt even look at the regex.  one sec

Comment: That makes sure that it's catching any whitespace... attempting to catch ONLY the first letter. Although now that I look at it, I sppose I can leave that \W out.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix hmm, just looked up \b, I guess I could have gotten away with `/\b([a-z])/` couldn't I.  Although that would uppercase the a in *an mentioned above.  Not sure if that is good or bad in your use case

Comment: Very interesting... I popped your regex into gskinner's regex and it doesn't seem to do what I think you expect. 

As for the regex I used, some people have multiple last names and we want to force the first letter of each to be capitalized. Came down from on high today that "Oh, some people have capitals in the middle of their last names." Okay...